# How do you query data from only the last file uploaded in cloud storage with BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Everyday I'm uploading a new file to a Cloud Storage bucket. The file is stored as JSON-NL format. I have a BigQuery table (setup as external table) connected to this bucket. Each files is named with the date of their upload. If I want to query only the most recent file, so far the best option I found is to parse the `_FILE_NAME` in my sql query and match it with the current date. However the parsing is a bit messy so I'm wondering is there is any other better solution.

What are other options to query only the most recent file? Should I set this up differently?

Comment: There isn't better solution. Use a script to parle the pseudo-column with the file name, get the latest one and then query it (with an execute immediate). No other solution so far

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't better solution. Use a script to parse the pseudo-column with the file name, get the latest one and then query it (with an execute immediate). No other solution so far